# Проблема с тестированием с использованием withConsecutive()

Tags: php, phpunit

У меня есть класс с методами

```php
public function fillStatisticForAllTime(): void
{
    $firstDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->userPaymentsRepository->getTheOldestDate());
    $lastDate = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    while ($firstDate < $lastDate) {
        $this->fillStatistic($firstDate);
        $firstDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}

private function fillStatistic(DateTime $day): void
{
    $dateFrom = $day->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateTo = clone $day;
    $dateTo->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $statisticAll = $this->userPaymentsRepository
            ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => false]);
    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticAll, $day, false);

    $statisticOnlyPaid = $this->userPaymentsRepository
            ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => true]);
    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticOnlyPaid, $day, true);
}
```

Я пытаюсь написать на него тесты:

```php
public function testFillStatisticForAllTime(): void
{
    $dateFromFirst = (new \DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateToFirst = (new \DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'))->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $dateFromSecond = (new \DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateToSecond = (new \DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $statistic = ['addPeopleFromPlugin' => 10];
    $statisticOnlyPaid = ['addPeopleFromPlugin' => 7];

    $this->userPaymentsRepositoryMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getTheOldestDate')
        ->willReturn($dateFromFirst->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $this->userPaymentsRepositoryMock->expects($this->exactly(4))
        ->method('getSummaryStatistic')
        ->withConsecutive(
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromFirst, 'dateTo' => $dateToFirst, 'onlyPaid' => false]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromFirst, 'dateTo' => $dateToFirst, 'onlyPaid' => true]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromSecond, 'dateTo' => $dateToSecond, 'onlyPaid' => false]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromSecond, 'dateTo' => $dateToSecond, 'onlyPaid' => true]],
        )
        ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($statistic, $statisticOnlyPaid, $statistic, $statisticOnlyPaid);

    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepositoryMock->expects($this->exactly(4))
        ->method('insertDailyStatistic')
        ->withConsecutive(
            [$statistic, $dateFromFirst, false],
            [$statisticOnlyPaid, $dateFromFirst, true],
            [$statistic, $dateFromSecond, false],
            [$statisticOnlyPaid, $dateFromSecond, true],
        );

    $this->fillUserPaymentStatisticService->fillStatisticForAllTime();
}
```

Если я беру текущую дату и отнимаю от нее два дня то метод fillStatistic должен запустится 2 раза а методы репозиториев getSummaryStatistic и insertDailyStatistic 4 раза соответственно.
Сегодня 2020-02-07, соответственно методы репозиториев первые два раза должны вызваться с датой 2020-02-05, и два раза с датой 2020-02-06, однако вместо этого я получаю фейл:

```
Parameter 0 for invocation #0 App\Repositories\Members\Billing\UserPaymentsRepository::getSummaryStatistic(Array (...)): array does not match expected value.

Expected:
Array (
    'dateFrom' => 2020-02-05T00:00:00.000000+0000
    'dateTo' => DateTime Object (...)
    'onlyPaid' => false
)
Actual:
Array (
    'dateFrom' => 2020-02-06T00:00:00.000000+0000
    'dateTo' => DateTime Object (...)
    'onlyPaid' => false
)
```

Пробовал ставить var_dump($firstDate) в начале цикла в методе fillStatisticForAllTime, дата та что ожидается, но почему в тесте фейлится?
Видимо проблема как то связана с тем что в методе fillStatisticForAllTime я передаю один и тот же обьект даты, если же поменять на

```
while ($firstDate < $lastDate) {
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $firstDate->format('U'));
    $this->fillStatistic($date);
    $firstDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

то все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте `$firstDate` с датой и временем, затем передаёте этот объект в метод `fillStatistic` и в нём у того же самого объекта меняете время на 00:00:00. Затем вы сравниваете эту дату с нулевым временем с текущей датой, у которой время тоже сброшено на ноль, видимо, не учитывая что дату поменяли в другой функции.

```php
$firstDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', ...);
$this->fillStatistic($firstDate);
```

```php
private function fillStatistic(DateTime $day): void
{
    $dateFrom = $day->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    // $dateFrom и $day здесь тот же самый объект
```

В такой ситуации не стоит ожидать такого поведения, какое вам нужно. Что вы и наблюдаете, когда заменяете объект даты на новый перед вызовом функции. Аналогично должно помочь отправлять копию объекта даты.

```php
$this->fillStatistic(clone $firstDate);
```

Можно порекомендовать вам выделить логику работы с датами в отдельный класс или метод, который на входе будет получать дату начала и дату конца, выдавая последовательность дат типа `DateTimeImmutable`, для которых уже вы ведёте учёт. Такое выделение позволит существенно упростить тесты, устранив необходимость использовать в них моки: достаточно будет проверить только что для двух дат получается правильная последовательность.

Даже если не выделять эту логику в отдельную сущность, использование `DateTimeImmutable` и `DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable` должно указать вам на все слабые места и устранить возможность появления таких ошибок в дальнейшем.